# Automate Emails for Attendance

Tags: email, templates, automation, contacts

We want to automate sending emails to people if they do not attend meetings for over two weeks. We have a list of attendees and their contact information, and we want to create a template to send via email and if possible, via text. The frequency will be every two weeks for people who have not been in attendance.

Is there a best way to go about this? Should we use a marketing tool like Survey Monkey?

We are just looking for information and ideas at this stage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Questions like yours that are seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, ... are most likely leading to opinion-based answers and are thus off topic on this site.